# Как запустить в c# другое приложение из моего, чтобы оно не являлось дочерним?

Tags: c#

Как запустить в c# другое приложение из моего, чтобы оно не являлось дочерним? Т.е при запуске с моего приложения, то приложение, которое надо запустить, открывалось не как дочернее.

Comment: Process.Start();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в ответах к [этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8434379/start-new-process-without-being-a-child-of-the-spawning-process) шестилетней давности предлагают запускать через промежуточный процесс

например **ken2k** пишет (Dec 8 '11)

> If you start a process, then you'll be its parent.
>
> Maybe you could try to start your process from `cmd.exe` instead, so **cmd.exe will be the parent**.
>
> ```
> Process proc = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo {
>   Arguments = "/C explorer",
>   FileName = "cmd",
>   WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden });
> ```

или **Pawel P** (Oct 24 '15)

> This runs new process without parent:
>
> ```
> System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi = new
> System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
> psi.FileName = @"cmd";
> psi.Arguments = "/C start notepad.exe";
> psi.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
> System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psi);
> ```

---

не адепт c#

на дворе 2018 и .NET есть в том числе и на линухах ...

---

**UPD:**

[JBSnorro](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47907872/4794368) (Dec 20 '17)

Документация к методу [Process.Start(string fileName)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.110).aspx) говорит

> a new process that’s started alongside already running instances 
>   of the same process will be independent
>
> новый процесс, запущенный рядом с уже запущенными экземплярами того же процесса будет независимым

и это значит

> Starting a process by specifying its file name is similar to 
>   typing the information in the Run dialog box of the Windows Start menu
>
> Запуск процесса путем указания его имени файла аналогичен запуску через диалоговое окно Пуск->меню->запустить приложение

что по моему мнению означает, что процесс запускается как независимый

Таким образом, следуя документации, `Process.Start` - это то. что вы ищете

Answer (score 0):

В using Windows.Diagnostic; есть класс Procces и у него метод Start который принимает в качестве аргумента ссылку на ексешник который нужно открыть.
  using Windows.Diagnostic;
    Procces.Start(@"D:\file.exe");

Comment: Вопрос перечитайте.

Comment: А в чем собственно разница? Я вообще термин "дочерного проекта" первый раз встречаю.

Comment: дочерний процесс